# Installing scss-lint with npm without Python

Tags: npm, gulp, node-sass, scss-lint

I'm trying to get [`gulp-scss-lint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scss-lint) to work on my machine, but having trouble doing so.

**Context**

I have a feeling specific versions and environment settings may be important to my issue, so let me list *my* specific context:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- NPM 2.14.7
- Node 4.2.2
- Gulp 3.9.0 installed `-g`
- Running from Powershell 4.0

**Repro**

Here's a repro of my problem:

1. `mkdir gulpscsslint` and `cd gulpscsslint`
2. `npm init` with all default answers
3. `npm install gulp --save-dev`
4. `npm install gulp-scss-lint --save-dev`
5. `new-item -itemtype file gulpfile.js` and enter:

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp'), lint = require('gulp-scss-lint');
   gulp.task('default', [], function() {
     return gulp.src('*.scss').pipe(lint());
   });
   ```
6. `new-item -itemtype file styles.scss`
7. `gulp`

Result:

> ```
>  [08:48:50] Using gulpfile ~\experiments\gulpscsslint\gulpfile.js
>  [08:48:50] Starting 'default'...
>  [08:48:50] 'default' errored after 32 ms
>  [08:48:50] Error in plugin 'gulp-scss-lint'
>  Message:
>      Error code 1
>  Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "scss-lint 'styles.scss' --format=JSON"
>  'scss-lint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>  operable program or batch file.
> ```

Expected result was obviously actual output from the linter.

So then I continued:

8. `npm install scss-lint --save-dev`

But it fails with `failNoPython`, with this snippet from the output:

> ```
>  Can not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/win32-x64-node-4.2/binding.node
>  gyp ERR! configure error
>  gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable
> ```

**Question**

Is it really a hard requirement to have *Python* to install this Node package? Or can it somehow be installed without installing Python?

As a footnote, now that I've fully written this question I realize this *might* be more something of a Github issue, but if so I might need some help (learning how to) find(ing) out what package or tool is giving me trouble (`gulp-scss-lint`? `scss-lint`? `npm`? `node-sass` or some other underlying package?).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually install the package by cloning or downloading it directly from it's [github repository](https://github.com/juanfran/gulp-scss-lint) and placing it into your targeted location.

Note:

> node-gyp is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for compiling native addon modules for Node.js. [Link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#node-gyp---nodejs-native-addon-build-tool)

This package requires Python to work. [Hundreds of packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/node-gyp), including **npm** and **npminstall**, rely on node-gyp to compile. On windows, a person can install the package windows-build-tools, which includes python, to use node-gyp.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful remark. It doesn't quite answer the main question I had though ("Is it really a hard requirement to have Python? / Can you install without Python?") - as I didn't _want_ to have Python on my machine just to be able to use some NPM package.

Comment: Thx . It's a shame that it requires Python, and interesting that when "hundreds" depend on it that I never otherwise encountered this limitation developing Express/Angular/Vue/etc apps...